# How to use multi-level SUBDIRS in Makefile.am:s?

Tags: automake, subdirectory

A common issue automake complains about is caused by following lines in various Makefile.am:s

```
Makefile.am:
SUBDIRS = deployment transport/http/util transport/http/common engine transport
```

The intent of this line is to force the order of building so that *transport/http/util* and *transport/http/common* are build before the *engine* directory, and building rest of the *transport* after engine is build.

This line causes the following error when running automake under MinGW:

```
Makefile.am:1: directory should not contain `/'
```

Comment: Resolved the issue, and added the solution to the end of the question.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer to the question and mark that answer as the solution. Then this question will be listed as "answered" for everybody's benefit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an old version of automake (at least 1.7 and older). Newer versions accept multi-level paths as values for SUBDIRS.